# How to add QGIS RasterToolbar function to PyQgis Plugin

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I want to be able to use these following Raster Toolbarfunctions in my pyqgis plugin. The plugin has a separate QMainWindow. Let's say my window is w and raster layer is called layer. I want to be able to call like

```
rt = mRasterToolbar()

w.layer.apply(rt.actions()[1])
```

However, I could not find a class I could initiate. The closest I got was

```
tb = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, "mRasterToolBar")

raster_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("raster_layer_name")[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(raster_layer)

tb.actions()[0].trigger()
```

But this applies to plugin running in iface. How to I add this to my plugin with a separate window?

[image: Image of the functions I want to apply]